# How to pass a generic type to a child function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
const foo = <T>(arg1: T): T => {
  return arg1
}

export type Bar = {
  foo: typeof foo
}

export const bar = <T>(): Bar => {
  return { foo }
}

bar<number>()
```

I need to pass the Generic `T` from `bar` to `foo` depending on the declaration in the last statement, such that this `T` would be the argument type as well as return type of `foo` i.e; `number` in this case. How can I make this happen?

*Please note that the* `bar` *and* `Bar` *are exported members of the module.*

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that the question was changed after this answer was written.*

---

Since your function `bar` doesn't have a return type annotation, its return type will be inferred as `{foo<T>(arg1: T): T}` (where the `T` is a free variable) using the declared type of `foo`. If you want the weaker type `{foo(arg1: T): T}` where the `T` is bound to the type parameter of `bar`, then you can just specify that in a return type annotation:

```
const bar = <T>(): {foo(x: T): T} => {
  return { foo }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVAfACgIYBOA5gIwBcMGAlBRiljAN4CwAUDDAQKZQCuBYGIVJsAvmzahIsAEaEU6bDhpMEIHAA9aKjKPpM2HbnwFN4iGONZW2cgmjC8AtjK4FcVIA)

Comment: I have just edited the question to add a return type for bar (which is actually my real problem)

Comment: So the answer is: don't do that, do what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: This won't work in case you need to export the type Bar.

Comment: Then what you want is logically impossible: you want `Bar` to specify that the `foo` property has the type `typeof foo`, which is a generic function with its own type parameter, but you also want the `foo` property to not have its own type parameter. That is clearly contradictory.

Comment: Alright. I'll try to come up with some solution. Will post if successful.